How can i force an inputs placeholder to wrap across multiple lines
I have a input trait that i want to force the placeholders to wrap across multiple lines due to space constraints
i tried to use the inputs provide properties for overflowWrap and textOverflow also over but this only affected the input itself

The placeholder element is unfortunately quite tricky when it comes to how various browsers handle it. More info on that and possible workarounds here
However, it is possible to get this working in Chrome and Edge (Firefox will not work and while I'm not 100% sure, I don't think Safari will work either). Here's a simple example that will get you started:
{
    "type": "input",
    "prps": {
        "placeholder": "long placeholder that you would like to wrap",
        "height": "200px",
        "style": {
            ".cpnInput input::placeholder": {
                "white-space": "pre-line"
            }
        }
    }
}

